# What is the best way to handle translations without a backend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am currently creating a maintenance page for my site. I'm using the app_offline option with asp.net mvc. My site handles translations in the back end however using the app_offline page I won't be able to do this as all requests will be redirected to this page. My idea was that I could get the language settings from the browser and change the text depending on the county code but I was curious if there was a better way. I found an answer on here that showed me how to do this in javascript but I'd still like to see if there is any other ways. The javascript answer was to have a list like below with the each item the class is a country code.

```
        <ul class="text">
            <li class="en active">Maintenance Mode</li>
            <li class="fr">Mode maintenance</li>
            <li class="es">Modo de mantenimiento</li>
            <li class="nl">Maintenance Mode</li>
            <li class="pt_BR">Modo de Manutenção</li>
            <li class="pt_PT">Modo de Manutenção</li>
            <li class="de">Wartungsmodus</li>
        </ul>
```

And then using javascript and jQuery you either hide or show the row that matches the current browser language.

```
    var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    if($('.' + userLang.split('-')[0]).length) {
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $('.' + userLang.split('-')[0]).addClass('active');
    }
```

Is there any better ways to do this? I've managed to add images to the page by using Base64 encoding so I don't have to host them elsewhere since I can't request them from the site but translations are the more important issue. I am not sure if this is the correct section to post this question so I am sorry if its not. Thank you for any help and suggestions.

Comment: I think what you have already is a good solution.